# What does JSS mean?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In *The Walking Dead* TV show, in the first couple of episodes where Enid comes in, she is alone and is leaving the letters JSS in everything and everywhere.

Why and what does JSS mean?

Comment: JavaScript Sofware :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Just survive somehow.

Here we have an image

[image: jss]

A letter, with JSS- just survive somehow.

Comment: HAHA @Bleh that's kinda what I  thought it meant but I wasn't sure. Thx!

Comment: They really tied it in that episode, but I feel like an episode or two later someone said the phrase again to her out of nowhere. I feel like it was either Glen or more likely Carl.